# Use SharePoint components in existing MVC3 website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sharepoint-2010

Hello StackOV experts!

I've just completed the core pieces of my first MVC3 site.  While showcasing it to folks, I received additional requirements (Wiki and document library being the ones of concern here).

One of the other developers suggested using SharePoint components to address the feature needs.  We have a SharePoint server.  Can we use the SharePoint components and incorporate them in the current site without overhauling the website to SharePoint? If so, can you please provide some examples?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... those are the key features which make SP solution win over any ASP.Net or MVC application.

Anyway , few options you have is to write custom UI 
and use client object model / Rest APIs to post and pull data from SP2010

If you are using MOSS 2007 then you can look into "SPServices" project in Codeplex , which uses JQuery + SP2007 Webservice to give you kind of same behaviour.

There will be lot of limitation also as you will not be able to use Office Integration from MVC application as you can do in SP2010.

Comment: Can you please provide me the some link so i start implementing it into my existing or in my new project.